# tmux / screen ctrl+arrow (left right) doesn't work on SSH

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, gnu-screen, tmux

I've configured `tmux` to skip words on Ctrl+right / left :

`set-window-option -g xterm-keys on`

It works just fine, but as I do SSH, it doesn't work and prints `;5D` or `;5C`..

The same issue occurred when I used `screen`, is there some specific configuration for `tmux`/`screen` on SSH ?

Comment: I don't know a solution to this, so I'm only providing a comment, not an answer. No Debian-based system has ever done this to me, but this is a common case on my CentOS systems. Just use Alt+b and Alt+f to move backward and forward respectively. My guess is this is more standard and should work without any hassle.

Comment: Alt+b does work, Alt+f opens the 'file' menu.
But I see no reason why it wouldn't work...

Comment: Then you probably have a system-wide keyboard shortcut assigned to Alt+f, which overrides the terminal default.

Comment: What terminal are you using? Are you using gnome-terminal?

Comment: Are you using SSH inside tmux or the other way round? What escape sequence do you expect these keys to send — this isn't standardized and `\e[1;5D` is one of the popular choices.

Comment: I'm opening a new terminal which start `tmux` as start command, then I do SSH, I'm not sure what I expect but I can't see why it should be different than non-SSH usage.

Comment: Also posted on Superuser: http://superuser.com/questions/882840/

Comment: The answer on Superuser was good enough, should have been accepted and this one closed.